# How can I fix Error during migration generation NESTJS?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, backend, typeorm

I tried to perform a migration with NestJS and TypeORM following a course, but encountered this error:

`npm run m:gen -- ./migrations/init`

> backend@0.0.1 m:gen
> export NODE_ENV=development && npm run orm:init migration:generate ./migrations/init
>
> backend@0.0.1 orm:init
> typeorm-ts-node-esm -d ./src/config/data.source.ts migration:generate ./migrations/init
>
> Error during migration generation:
> Error: Unable to open file: "/Users/diego/Developer/CRUD-node/backend/src/config/data.source.ts". Cannot use import statement outside a module
> at CommandUtils.loadDataSource (/Users/diego/Developer/CRUD-node/backend/node_modules/typeorm/commands/CommandUtils.js:22:19)
> at async Object.handler (/Users/diego/Developer/CRUD-node/backend/node_modules/typeorm/commands/MigrationGenerateCommand.js:73:26)`

These are the commands I use in the package.json file:

> "orm:init": "typeorm-ts-node-esm -d ./src/config/data.source.ts",
> "m:gen": "export NODE_ENV=development && npm run orm:init migration:generate",
> "m:run": "export NODE_ENV=development && npm run orm:init migration:run"

I don't know why they can't open the file. This is the data.source.ts file:

```
> import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
> import { DataSource, DataSourceOptions } from 'typeorm';
> import { SnakeNamingStrategy } from 'typeorm-naming-strategies';
> 
> ConfigModule.forRoot({
> envFilePath: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}.local`,
> });
> 
> const configService = new ConfigService();
> 
> export const DataSourceConfig: DataSourceOptions = {
> type: 'postgres',
> host: configService.get('DB_HOST'),
> port: configService.get('DB_PORT'),
> username: configService.get('DB_USER'),
> password: configService.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
> database: configService.get('DB_NAME'),
> entities: [__dirname + '/../**/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
> migrations: [__dirname + '/../../migrations/*{.ts,.js}'],
> synchronize: false,
> migrationsRun: true,
> logging: false,
> namingStrategy: new SnakeNamingStrategy(),
> };
> 
> export const AppDS = new DataSource(DataSourceConfig);
```

I tried to convert the file into a module, but it threw a new error. I don't know why this error occurred or how to fix it